# How to enable element using siblings jquery

Tags: jquery

Looking below i would like to get the value of the cnhor element and if its equal to
"Guide" enable the corresponding button.
Tried the below but couldn't get it to work.:(
Have a feeling i'm almost there.
Thanks

```
 $("button").siblings("a").each(function () {
                    var b = $(this).text();
                    var n = $.trim("Guide");


                    if ($.trim(b) == n) {

                        $("button").removeAttr("disabled");

                    }


  <button id="Toggle5" disabled="disabled">
                        Show </button>
                    <a href="#" id="docsID5" target="_blank">

                        Guide 
                    </a>
```

Comment: Let us see the HTML for the cnhor element.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9gahF/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the close bracket/parenthesis:

```
 $("button").siblings("a").each(function () {
                    var b = $(this).text();
                    var n = $.trim("Guide");


                    if ($.trim(b) == n) {

                        $("button").removeAttr("disabled");

                    }
});
```

It helps to check out the JS console from time to time

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `removeProp()` instead of `removeAttr()`? Same signature, but designed for working with DOM properties (such as disabled) instead of attributes